# 既存カラムのデフォルト値をNULLへ変更したい

Tags: mysql

既存カラムのデフォルト値をNULLへ変更したいと思い、phpMyAdminのSQL欄で

```
ALTER TABLE `t` ALTER COLUMN `hoge` SET DEFAULT NULL;
```

を実行したら、構文エラーとなりました。

> 新しいステートメントが見つかりましたが、それとその前の間に区切り文字がありません

---

次に下記を試したら、期待通り実行できたのですが、

```
ALTER TABLE `t` CHANGE `hoge` `hoge` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

「ALTER COLUMN」と「CHANGE」は、どう使い分けるのですか？
既存カラムのデフォルト値を設定変更する場合は、「ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT」を使用するものとばかり思っていたのですが、違うのですか？

環境
MySQL5.7

Comment: タイトルと本文の後半とで質問内容が噛み合っていないように見えます。(変更自体はできたのでは？)

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通り、前の行が `;`(セミコロン)で終わっていないので、`ALTER TABLE \`t\` 〜` が継続している SQL 文だと解釈(parse)されたのだと思います。[SQL Fiddle の MySQL 5.7 で確認してみると](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVAKg8qbsRuurSi862ocJJ/1)エラーにはなりません。

Comment: この一文だけを実行しているのですが、このSQL文自体には問題がないと考えてよいですか？　SQL Fiddle でも正常実行されるとなると、phpMyAdminの問題としか考えられないのですが……

Comment: はい、問題ないはずです。phpMyAdmin ではなく、mysql コマンドで実行してみてエラーになるのかどうかを確認してみると問題の切り分けができるかもしれません。

Comment: 以前は「SET DEFAULT」実行できていたので、これで原因の切り分けができたと思います。余裕ができた時に、phpMyAdminをアップデートしたいと思います